# no click event in (some) Internet Explorers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have problems with jquery-click-Events on Button-Elements not firing in some Internet Explorers.

This is not related to submitting forms, I found many questions regarding problems with this, but no duplicate with this question.

I made a very simple example to illustrate the problem:

It is only a Test-Button, initially colored red to prove that jQuery works and with a click handler colouring it blue and showing an alert.
Here is my jQuery Code :

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(){
  $('#foo').css('color', 'blue');
  alert('test');
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="foo">Test</button>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, that the click event does not fire on some PCs in Internet Explorer. On other PCs it works in IE and on all PCs in all other browsers.

Here is a screenshot of a not working IE:
[image: not working example]

I searched through all Options and compatibility modes and did not find a solution/reason for this.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: did you checked this way
   $(document).on('click','#foo',function(){
$('#foo').css('color', 'blue');
  alert('test');
})

Comment: I just found out, that mouseup-events with jquery work and that it works to use `document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() {... }` without jquery.

Comment: Hi Karan, I checked your suggestion using delegates, it does not work either.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `addEventListener` method? Can you check if it is available?
`document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function(){..})`
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Does the console output anything? The code seems fine

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to open a console in this Internet Explorer. Maybe it is broken? I'll try the addEventListener...